# The request could not be satisfied in while using <alphaNumeric-string>.cloudFront.net

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Here I am facing the same issue. Got my CNAME alias as aws.phonon.in which is working perfectly. But got a scenario where i have to redirect users to cloudfront.net url which is mapped to my CNAME.

Below are the details:

https://aws.phonon.in/c2cReports/resource/images/PhonOnlogo.png
This link works as expected. 
My aws.phonon.in is mapping to the A record : d1f4zd5av6bosa.cloudfront.net
But if i try to hit the url: https://d1f4zd5av6bosa.cloudfront.net/c2cReports/resource/images/PhonOnlogo.png

I get the 502 bad gateway error.

I'm able to telnet on both port 80 and 443.
I can provide more details

Please get me out of this....

Comment: I think what might help is verbose curl outputs for 3 cases - hitting your cname, hitting cloudfront.net, and hitting your origin directly. However this is very specific question, and CloudFront forum / tech support might be more appropriate place to ask it

Comment: It is a problem is certificate. The cloudfront certificate has been overridden by my custom certificate.                                         Thanks for paying attention anyways.........